# Can I fix MediaQuery.of(context) to constant value?

Tags: dart, flutter

To make responsive application, I'm using `MediaQuery.of(context)` for every component size, but it is hard working to write for each section.

Therefore, I fixed it to constant and is it right handling?

```
class ScreenUtil {
  static double width;
  static double height;
}
void initializeConstants(BuildContext context){
  ScreenUtil.width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  ScreenUtil.height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  CurrentPlatform.platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is a bad idea.

The reason why we need `.of(context)` is to always fetch the latest object so we can ensure that the widget correctly updates itself when the inherited value changes.

The `MediaQuery.of(context).size` is not a constant. Instead it will dynamically update itself when the user rotate the screen, for example, from portrait mode to horizontal mode, and in that scenario its `width` and `height` would get flipped.

It is not a good idea in general to strip any of the `.of(context)` off and assuming they are constants. The time complexity of calling this method is O(1) according to [Flutter's in-code dartdoc](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6a5ef29a75c7fe8c2f8af393e7daed09a34c4027/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L2063):

> Calling this method is O(1) with a small constant factor, but will
>   lead to the widget being rebuilt more often.